# java threads simple stupid program

Tags: java, multithreading

i hope someone will help me. I have been trying to make a traffic light with java Threads.
There are two circles. Each circle is a lamp (thread). I would like each lamp to work for x ms and then turn off and let the other lamp work (again for some seconds and again..)

```
public void run()
{
    while (true)
    {           
        repaint();
        if (working)
        {
            System.out.println(name + " is WORKING ");
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(LAMP_WORKING_TIME);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(name + " has done working");

            synchronized (lock)
            {
                this.working = false;
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println(name + " is waiting..");

                synchronized (lock)
                {
                    lock.wait();
                    working = true;
                }

                System.out.println(name + " is WAKING UP AFTER WAIT");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When lock is declared as a property of the class:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
```

I believe my problem occurs by wait/notify methods.
Please, help me fix that!

Comment: It is not my homework. No one is gonna check it. It is a preparation to a test.

Comment: You should include more code.  Where and how do you define `working` and `lock`?

Comment: Also, I don't know if you were doing that to learn wait/notify, but if not, you should know that they are somewhat deprecated and you should use the utilities in java.util.concurrent instead.  But in your case it looks like a Swing Timer does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to make your `lock` shared between instances. So either make it `static` or pass it to your `Runnables`/`Threads` as a parameter instead of creating a new one for each instance, even if it's `final`.

Answer (score 2):

As your code reads, it will wait `LAMP_WORKING_TIME` ms, set working to false and on the next loop immediately set it back to true. You're only sleeping when it `working` is true, so your "on" cycle is `LAMP_WORKING_TIME` and the "off" cycle is just as long as it takes to release and reacquire the lock. Probably less than 1ms.

Comment: With eclipse debugger I don't reach the line where working=true (after the wait in the lock block)